# Letterbox / Crop 16:9 screen while displaying in 4:3?

Tags: linux, resolution

Example: I have a 1920x1080 monitor, but I want to use it in 800x600

When doing so, it runs along the entire monitor distorting what it would really look like. (This is also a problem for 1:1 mouse movement up and down)

I can't find a setting for this in `arandr` or `nvidia-settings`. How would one achieve this, `xrandr`? Can anyone give me a nice snippet solution?

Comment: See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/how-to-set-scaling-mode-for-external-displays-on-intel-gpu