# Reader view with monitor

Tags: linux, xorg, display, xrandr

I have a monitor whose native resolution is 1920x1080. I want to only use part of the monitor (eg., 960x1080):

```
+-----+------+-----+
|     |++++++|     |
|     |++++++|     |
|     |++++++|     |
|     |++++++|     |
|     |++++++|     |
+-----+------+-----+
```

or maybe (eg., 1600x900):

```
+---+------+---+
|              |
|   +------+   |
|   |++++++|   |
|   |++++++|   |
|   +------+   |
|              |
+---+------+---+
```

The blank space is where the monitor is black and the plus signs in the middle is where the screen is.

I have tried modifying the solution in [Due to a broken monitor, I need to setup only the right half of my screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127911/due-to-a-broken-monitor-i-need-to-setup-only-the-right-half-of-my-screen), but it always looks like this (extends to the right and bottom):

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --transform 1.5,0,-480,0,1.5,-270,0,0,1`

Monitor displays

```
+---+------+---+
|              |
|   +----------|
|   |++++++++++|
|   |++++++++++|
|   |++++++++++|
|   |++++++++++|
+---+------+---+
```

Wanted

```
+---+------+---+
|              |
|   +------+   |
|   |++++++|   |
|   |++++++|   |
|   +------+   |
|              |
+---+------+---+
```

How can I get a reader view on monitor? It would be best if the pixels weren't scaled, but being able to choose a particular resolution and have it centered on the monitor. For example, a 1280x720 centered on monitor and not 1920x1080 scaled down and centered on monitor.

A simple `xrandr -s 1600x900` changes to 1600x900 and zooms to fit the 1920x1080 monitor.

---

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1024x768 --panning 1024x768 --transform 1.33333333,0,-171,0,1,0,0,0,1` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220388/384272 makes monitor display

```
+-----+------+-----+
|     |++++++++++++|
|     |++++++++++++|
|     |++++++++++++|
|     |++++++++++++|
|     |++++++++++++|
+-----+------+-----+
```

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "scaling mode" "Center"` gives me:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  32
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```